# Add Remove Row With Get Total And Discount

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Add/Remove Row Example Already Worked. i have Problem Discount. How To Set Discound Using This Example.

Add/Remove Row Example Already Worked. i have Problem Discount. How To Set Discound Using This Example.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/Nilesh_Patel/00ar5frs/ Example Here

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".add").click(function () {
var length = $('.one').length;
var cloned = $(this).closest('.one').clone(true);        
cloned.appendTo("#mainDiv").find('.sno').val(length + 1);
cloned.find(':input:not(".sno")').val(" ");

cloned.find("input[onKeyUp*='showHint']").attr('onKeyUp', 'showHint' + (length+1)+'(this.value)');
cloned.find("input[id*='item_name']").attr('id', 'item_name' + (length+1));

var parent = $(this).closest('.one');
calculate(parent);
});
$('.delete').click(function () {
if($('.one').length==1){
alert("This is default row and can't deleted");
return false;
}
var parent = $(this).closest('.one');
$(this).parents(".one").remove();
calculate(parent);
// reset serial numbers again
$('.one').each(function(index, item) {
$(this).find('.sno').val(index+1);

$(this).find("input[onKeyUp*='showHint']").attr('onKeyUp', 'showHint' + (index+1)+'(this.value)');
$(this).find("input[id*='item_name']").attr('id', 'item_name' + (index+1));
})
});
});

$(document).on('keyup', '.quantity, .net_rate, .Gross_Rate, .Discount_rate', function () {
var parent = $(this).closest('.one');
calculate(parent);
})


function calculate(e){
var q = +$(e).find('.quantity').val();
var n = +$(e).find('.net_rate').val();
var t = +$(e).find('.tax').val();
var d = +$(e).find('.Discount_rate').val();
var sum = 0;


$(e).find('.Gross_Rate').val(g=q*n*t/100);
$(e).find('.total').val((q*n)+g);
$(e).find('.Discount_rate').val(k=g-d);

$('.total').each(function(i,e){
sum += +$(e).val();    
});
$('#Grand').val(sum);
};


<div id="mainDiv">
<div class="one">
<div class="row">

<div class="input-field col s1">
<input type="text" class="sno" name="Sr[]" value="1"  readonly>
<label for="Sr" >Sr</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s1">
<input type="text" class="quantity"  name="Quantity[]" value=" ">
<label for="Quantity" >Quantity</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s1">
<input type="text" class="net_rate" name="net_rate[]" value=" ">
<label for="net_rate" >Net Rate</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s1">
<input type="text" class="tax" name="tax[]" value=" ">
<label for="tax" >tax</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s1">
<input type="text" class="Gross_Rate" name="gross_rate[]" value=" " readonly >
<label for="Gross Rate" >Gross Rate</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s1">
<input type="text" class="total" name="total[]" value=" " readonly>
<label for="total" >total</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col s1 add">
<a href="#">Add</a>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s1 delete">
<a href="#"> Remove</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="input-field col s6"></div>

<div class="input-field col s1">
<input type="text" name="Discount_rate" id="Discount_rate" class="Discount_rate" value=" ">
<label for="Discount_rate" >Discount</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s1">
<input type="text" name="Discount_tax" id="Discount_tax" class="Discount_tax"  value=" ">
<label for="Discount_tax" >Discount(%)</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s2">
<input type="text" name="Grand_total" id="Grand" class="Grand" value=" " readonly>
<label for="Grand_total" >Grand Total</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should change your javascript from : `$(e).find('.Discount_rate').val();` to `$('.Discount_rate').val();`

Comment: Confused in **Discount** & **Discount(%)**... at list write some calculation description

Comment: Mr. Alex Thomas I Want To 2 type Discount (1) Any Amount Or (2) In discount(%) This Two Different condition.

Comment: (1) i Added Discount_rate Then discount_tax Empty. And Added Discount_tax Then Discount_rate Empty...

Comment: Alex Thomas As Above Two Comments Say Me Ans...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment:

> Mr. Alex Thomas I Want To 2 type Discount (1) Any Amount Or (2) In
>   discount(%) This Two Different condition. –  Nilesh
>
> (1) i Added Discount_rate Then discount_tax Empty. And Added
>   Discount_tax Then Discount_rate Empty... –  Nilesh

I have prepared the solution [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcwn4382/1/)

I have check first `Discount_rate` and if it is not a number then check for `Discount_tax` for calculating discount..

```
    var disc = $('.Discount_rate').val();
    if(parseInt(disc) > 0)
    {
        $('.Discount_tax').val('');
        $('#Grand').val(sum-$('.Discount_rate').val());
    }
    else
    {
        $('.Discount_rate').val('');
        disc = $('.Discount_tax').val();
        if(parseInt(disc) > 0)
            $('#Grand').val(sum-(parseInt(disc)*sum/100));
        else
            $('#Grand').val(sum);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks For Me help  Mr. Sac

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I 100% understand the question. But I think you need to change the last line:

```
$('#Grand').val(sum);
```

to this:

```
$('.Discount_tax').val($('.Discount_rate').val()/sum*100);
$('#Grand').val(sum-$('.Discount_rate').val());
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcwn4382/)